# how to configure enterprise library 6 in visual studio 2017 / windows 10

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017, enterprise-library

I have a project I created back in VS 2015 with enterprise library for logging. Now with VS 2017 I cannot install any plugin for EL6 any more, also I downloaded the EL binaries but whenever I try to start the 32 or 64 bit EntLibConfig executable, the stop working right at the splash screen. 
I tried a reboot, run as admin and compatibility mode.

Is that just me or is there a general problem?
Should I switch to another logging library?

My VS just updated to VS 2017.3.1 and I run on Windows 10 1703 x64.

Sadly, I didn't find anything about EL and vs 2017 which made me quite confused.

Thanks

Comment: The last release for the enterprise library was April 2013 so it is not surprising it does work with vs 2017.  The code is still available on codeplex if you want to update it.

Comment: I know that it's not the newest. but as I am a newbie in c# I wanted to ask someone who actually knows that because it could also be that I am making kind of a dumb mistake ;)
Sadly, I didn't find anything about that anywhere :/

Comment: you should be able to use the logging application block nuget package with visual studio 2017.  I would not expect the addin to work that makes it easy to update the config files.

Comment: it also depends on the type of project you are trying to create for example i dont think it would work with a .net core app

Answer (score 1):

As a result of the uncertainty about the future of EL, I switched to serilog.